# New DAC field from VS class

Tags: acumatica

I had to create a DAC extension in Visual Studio project instead of the DAC class into customization because I had to define dropdown values for few fields and I cannot create it if I extend DAC directly from customization.

Here is the code for DAC extension with dropdown field and its values, from Visual Studio project-

```html
public class SOOrderExtension : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder>
{
 #region Class DropDownValue
 public static class DropDownValue
 {
  public const string Value1 = "1";
  public const string Value2 = "2";
  public const string Value3 = "3";
 }
 #endregion

 #region UsrDropDown

 [PXDBString(1)]
 [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My DropDown")]
 [PXStringList(new string[]
 {
  DropDownValue.Value1, DropDownValue.Value2, DropDownValue.Value3
 },
 new string[]
 {
  "One", "Two", "Three"
 })]
 public virtual string UsrDropDown { get; set; }
 public abstract class usrDropDown : IBqlField { }

 #endregion
}
```

This is working fine and it has created new user defined fields into SOOrder existing table. However, if I add any new fields into this DAC extension class, it does not create new fields in SOOrder table and just skips when I publish my customization. Hence I need to add a SQL script to my customization to add those new fields into SOOrder table.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Ideally, it should create new fields into SOOrder table if I add new field in DAC extension in Visual Studio same as if I add new field in DAC extension directly into customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krunal, Acumatica will only create new columns in database when you declare new bound DAC field in customization project manager. There is no way to automatically create new column in database when someone declares new field in DAC extension directly in Visual Studio.

Please refer to the screenshot below showing how to declare your custom UsrDropDown directly in project manager:
[image]

Comment: Agreed. But what if there is some custom logic to that DAC extension and I need to reference it there. Such as SOOrderExtension currentSOOrxerExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtension>(current); Do you still think that can be done if I have DAC in customization project manager?

Comment: Could you please explain why you need to implement custom logic inside a DAC field getter/setter?

Comment: Not in Get/Set properties. I need to write into some GraphExtension. public class SOOrderEntryExtension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry> For example, I need to fill value in line item from this custom fields on button click.

Comment: For an example check Step 2.1: Adding the Verify Credit Record Action from the T300 training course

Comment: Thanks Ruslan, I will try that.